# rsync show error on mounted location

Tags: linux, backup, mount, rsync

I have windows share name as Data, which I have mounted on /backup/siyad/Data folder.

But when I am taking backup with rsync then it show error

rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/backup/siyad/Data" failed: Permission denied (13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]

My command is as below

rsync -avzh /home/siyad/Data/* /backup/siyad/Data/

Comment: What are the permissions of `/backup/siyad/Data` folders? Does the user running the `rsync` command have write permission to that folder?

Comment: Problem of windows share permission issue. In windows share it has read only permission.